# Force required to move a stationary object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

What force would be required to move a vehicle 20 feet. The vehicle weighs 5000lbs the brakes are engaged on all 4 wheels during this event.

Comment: You must mention acceleration of the car and I don't understood why you mentioned brakes and tyres.

Comment: See [Amonton's law](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=amonton%27s+law+friction)

Comment: If this is a practical (joke) question, then the answer is... DON'T!

Comment: if you have a treadmill, you need 0.01 N to push the button. Else provide more datas please